# OpenCV documentation says that "uchar" is "unsigned integer" datatype. How?

Tags: c++, opencv, types, console, output

I got confused with the openCV documentation mentioned [**here**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#fixed-pixel-types-limited-use-of-templates).

As per the documentation, if i create an image with **"uchar"**, the pixels of that image can store **unsigned integer**  values but if i create an image using the following code:

```
Mat image;
image = imread("someImage.jpg" , 0); // Read an image in "UCHAR" form
```

or by doing

```
image.create(10, 10, CV_8UC1);
for(int i=0; i<image.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=o; j<image.cols; j++)
    {
        image.at<uchar>(i,j) = (uchar)255;
    }
}
```

and then if i try to print the values using

```
cout<<"  "<<image.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

then i get some wierd results at terminal but if i use the following statement then i can get the values inbetween 0-255.

```
cout<<"  "<<(int)image.at<uchar>(i,j); // with TYPECAST
```

**Question:** Why do i need to do typecast to get print the values in range 0-255 if the image itself can store "unsigned integer" values.

Comment: Does it help at all to know that `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are all *integer types* per the standard? Maybe OpenCV just used really piss-poor vernacular in that sentence?

Comment: It is an integer that takes only 8 bit, you don't treat those bits as ascii codes

Comment: Right. `integer` is not the same as `32 bit integer`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: sorry but i am unable to understand your meaning due to my limited c++/opencv knowledge. does opencv docs also mean that "uchar" means "unsigned char" or not?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you try to find definition of `uchar` (which is pressing F12 if you are using Visual Studio), then you'll end up in OpenCV's **core/types_c.h**:

```
#ifndef HAVE_IPL
   typedef unsigned char uchar;
   typedef unsigned short ushort;
#endif
```

which standard and reasonable way of defining unsigned integral 8bit type (i.e. *"8-bit unsigned integer"*) since standard ensures that `char` always requires exactly 1 byte of memory. This means that:

```
cout << "  " << image.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

uses the overloaded `operator<<` that takes `unsigned char` (`char`), which prints passed value in form of character, not number.

Explicit cast, however, causes another version of `<<` to be used:

```
cout << "  " << (int) image.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

and therefore it prints numbers. This issue is not related to the fact that you are using OpenCV at all.

---

Simple example:

```
char           c = 56; // equivalent to c = '8'
unsigned char uc = 56;
int            i = 56;
std::cout << c << " " << uc << " " << i;
```

outputs: `8 8 56`

And if the fact that it is a template confuses you, then this behavior is also equivalent to:

```
template<class T>
T getValueAs(int i) { return static_cast<T>(i); }

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int main() {
    int i = 56;
    std::cout << getValueAs<uchar>(i) << " " << (int)getValueAs<uchar>(i);
}
```

Comment: sorry but i am unable to understand do they also mean that "uchar" means "unsigned char" or not?

Comment: so will it be ok if i do `float value = c;` where `uchar c = 255;` ?  Would i be able to get `value =255.0` if i try to print it?

Comment: @user2756695: There is implicit type conversion, or, to be more accurate: `uchar` will be "promoted" to `float`, so yes, it is ok.

Comment: But, **a byte is not necessarily 8 bits**, isn’t it?

Answer (score 6):

Simply, because although `uchar` is an integer type, the stream operation `<<` prints the character it represents, not a sequence of digits. Passing the type `int` you get a different overload of that same stream operation, which does print a sequence of digits.

Comment: +1 Basically, that was my original answer, it's really simple as that.

Comment: @LihO: yes indeed, I skimmed your answer and was just about to read it through to make sure it didn't contain any inaccuracies before upvoting it, when I thought that a much shorter version might also be useful :-)